# Does the 7.00 on Brigg & Stratton lawn mower indicate 7 horse power?

Tags: lawn-mower

[image]

I’m confused by this lawn mower label. Does the 7.00 on this Brigg & Stratton lawn mower indicate 7 horse power or does it mean 7 torque?

Answer (score 2):

Just like the label says. Ft.Lbs Torque as per [SAE J1940](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j1940_201210)
[image]
Generally it will be whatever the biggest number they can come up with is, in hopes that you'll ignore the fine print and say "7 is better than 3.5 or 5, or 6, I'll happily pay more for it." So gross torque and net torque are allowed by the standard, but it will almost always be gross, as it's a bigger number.

Comment: To convert to horsepower you'd need to know the engine RPM. See: https://auto.howstuffworks.com/question622.htm for how to do the conversion.